# Extract unique lines from files (with a pattern) recursively from directory/subdirectories

Tags: regex, perl

I have a huge java codebase (more than 10,000 java classes) that makes extensive use of CORBA (no documentation available on its usage though).

As first step to figure out the CORBA usage, I decided to scan entire codebase and extract/print unique lines which contain the pattern "**org.omg.CORBA**". These are usually in the import statements (e.g. import org.omg.CORBA.x.y.z).

I am newbie to Perl and want to know if there is a way I can extract these details on Windows OS. I need to be able to scan all folders (and sub-folders) that have java classes.

Comment: Do you have cygwin installed? If you have cygwin or mysysgit installed, you can do `grep -rl '<keyword>' .` to recursively search for all files that import the class.

Comment: I thought you said "folders and subfolders", meaning a recursive search, and then you accept an answer which doesn't even check subfolders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind) in a one-liner:

```
perl -MFile::Find -lwe "
    find(sub { if (-f && /\.java$/) { push @ARGV,$File::Find::name } },'.'); 
    while(<>) { /org.omg.CORBA/ && $seen{$_}++; }; 
    print for keys %seen;"
```

Note that this one-liner is using the double quotes required for Windows.

This will search the current directory recursively for files with extension `.java` and add them to the `@ARGV` array. Then we use the diamond operator to open the files and search for the string `org.omg.CORBA`, and if it is found, that line is added as a key to the `%seen` hash, which will effectively remove duplicates. The last statement prints out all the unique keys in the hash.

In script form it looks like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

find(sub { if (-f && /\.java$/) { push @ARGV,$File::Find::name } },'.');
my %seen;
while(<>) {
    /org.omg.CORBA/ && $seen{$_}++; 
}
print "$_\n" for keys %seen;"
```

Comment: I accidently accepted the other answer even though I used this one for my problem. Being a newbie to Perl, I can't really speak much on other answers but the one-liner provided here gave me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, a perl one-liner to do this:

```
perl -lne '/org.omg.CORBA/ and (++$seen{$_}>1 or print)' *
```

This first checks if a line matches and then if it has not seen it before prints out the line. That is done for all files specified (in this case '*').

Answer (score 2):

i don't mean to be contrarian, but i'm not sure perl is the best solution here. nhahtdh's suggestion of using [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is a good one. grep or find is really what you want. using perl in this instance will involve using [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.0/lib/File/Find.pm) and then opening a filehandle on every file. that's certainly do-able, but, if possible, i'd suggest using the right tool for the job.

```
find . -name "*.java" -type f | xargs grep -l 'org.com.CORBA' | sort | uniq
```

if you really must use perl for this job we can work up the File::Find code.